# pry gem is not working on ruby 2 & it got stuck

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, automation, cucumber

Let me write a simple example

```
a = 2

b = 6

c = a + b
puts c
require 'pry-debugger'
binding.pry
puts c
```

when I do this

```
    34: 
    35: c = a + b
    36: puts c
    37: require 'pry-byebug'
    38: binding.pry
 => 39: puts c

[1] pry(main)> puts b
```

After this `puts b`, I am not seeing any result at all, no matter how many times I do it. Why is that, and how should I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read `pry-debugger` [README](https://github.com/nixme/pry-debugger#using-mri-200-use-pry-byebug)

> Using MRI 2.0.0+? Use [pry-byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug).

Comment: I tried using pry-byebug, its the same case...    43: def some_method
    44:   puts 'Hello World' # Run 'step' in the console to move here
    45: end
    46: 
    47: binding.pry
 => 48: some_method          # Execution will stop here.
    49: puts 'Goodbye World' # Run 'next' in the console to move here.

[1] pry(main)> blah blah................................     no matter what commands I give here its all taking as notepad nothing happening... btw am using rubymine editor with cucumber

Answer (score -1):

Are you using GitBash?

It wasn't working for me in GitBash but I tried it in Command Prompt and works fine.